# DateDiff not working when finding amount of years between two dates

Tags: vba

I've got the following formula

```
  number_of_years = DateDiff("yyyy", Date_days_back, Current_Date)
```

where
Date_days_back = 17/10/2020
Current_Date = 02/08/2021

for some reason this returns "1" when there aren't 365 days apart between these two dates, is something wrong with my formula or is DateDiff calculating this wrong? I would like to get "0" returned as there aren't enough amount of days between these two dates for a year to have passed between the two dates.

Comment: As Scott Stated, if I'm looking from December 31st 2020 and 1st of January 2021, then this function will count this as a year has passed. is there another function that calculates if a years has passed in between two dates where it doesn't do what DateDiff does and instead counts if 365 have passed in between the two dates?

Comment: `When comparing December 31 to January 1 of the immediately succeeding year, DateDiff for Year ("yyyy") returns 1 even though only a day has elapsed.` from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function)

Comment: @ScottCraner is there a function that I can use that will avoid this?

Comment: `Int((Current_date - Date_days_back)/365)` but that does not account for leap year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [YearFrac()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8). By setting the third argument to 1, the function uses the actual number of days in years (taking into account leap years) in its calculations:

```
Int(WorksheetFunction.YearFrac("2020-12-31", "2021-12-31", 1))
```

Comparison:

```
Sub Example()
    start_date = CDate("2020-12-31")
    end_date = CDate("2021-01-01")
    
    Debug.Print Int(WorksheetFunction.YearFrac(start_date, end_date, 1))
    ' prints 0
    Debug.Print DateDiff("yyyy", start_date, end_date)
    ' prints 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: Interesting behaviour when `start_date` > `end_date`, it sill counts full years (unlike mine) but returns a positive number (also unlike mine). Edge cases are fun!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
function yeardiff(d1 as date, d2 as date) as integer
     yeardiff = datediff("yyyy", d1, dateadd("yyyy", -1, dateadd("d", 1, d2)))
end function
```

Tests

```
print yeardiff("2020-12-31", "2021-12-30")
0

print yeardiff("2020-12-31", "2021-12-31")
1
```

Of course it will also give,

```
print yeardiff("2020-12-31", "2020-12-30")
-1
```

And if something different is desired then a conditional would be needed.